# Nombre de columna invalida SQL Server-Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-2.7, stored-procedure

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación que depende de SQL Server y desarrollo en Python. Toma datos de una `Sp` de `SQL Server` que trae por defecto de nombre:

`xp_readerrorlog 6, 1, N'login', N'failed'`

Como ve mando a traer resultados donde fallen los login atravez de python de la siguiente manera:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
#Libreias
#import pymssql
from time import sleep
import os,sys
from pprint import pprint

import pymssql

reload(sys) sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

#-------------------------------------------------------------
#atributos de conexión
server = "XP-AX"
user = "olis"
password = "Monitor"
base = "StoragePython"
#Conexion almacena la consulta de la BD de StoragePython
Conection = "select se.servidor, se.[user], se.Pass, sc.query, sc.tabla, ses.idq from servers se left join ServerScript ses on se.Servidor = ses.IdServidor left join scripts sc on ses.idq = sc.idq where ses.status = 1 and se.status = 1 order by se.servidor, ses.idq "
validacion = "XPSATURNO"

#crea una función con los parametros (server, user, password, base) a fin de poder utilizarlos dentro de la misma
def ejecutaSp(server, user, password, base):
#Para evitar que se levante la excepción y se detenga la ejecución del programa se crea un bloque de ejecución try-except
try:
    #Se almacena la información de EXEC en la variable qeury
    query = "EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 6, 1, N'login', N'failed'"

    #Coneccion a sql
    con = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, base)
    cursor = con.cursor() #Crea un cursor
    cursor.execute(query)#Ejecuta la consulta


    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        resultado = row[0], row[1], row[2]
        print resultado
        insert = "INSERT INTO prueba(fechahora,descripcion) VALUES(" + '"' + str(row[0]) + '"' + "," + '"' + (row[2] or '') + '"' + ")"
        print insert
        try:
            cursor.execute(insert)
            con.commit()
        except Exception as error:
            print('Ocurrió un problema al insertar: ' + str(error))
            exit(0)
except Exception as error:
    print('Ocurrió un problema en la conexión con el servidor principal: ' + server + ' e usuario: ' + user + ' - ' + str(error))
```

El resultado del print es el siguiente y junto al error es este:

> (datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 3, 17, 6, 9, 880000), u'Logon', u"Login failed for user 'GRUPOXCARET\edejesus'. Reason: Could not
>   find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.248.56.69]")
>       INSERT INTO prueba(fechahora,descripcion) VALUES("2017-03-03 17:06:09.880000","Login failed for user 'GRUPOXCARET\edejesus'.
>   Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT:
>   10.248.56.69]")
>       Ocurrió un problema al insertar: (207, "Invalid column name '2017-03-03 17:06:09.880000'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity
>   16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
>   Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server
>   error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Lo chistoso que al copiar e insertar el insert que esta arriba en el SQl Server, este sí funciona :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que tiene algo que ver con " y '.

Intenta con esto

```
insert = "INSERT INTO prueba(fechahora,descripcion) VALUES('" str(row[0]) + "','" + (row[2].replace('\'','\'\'')) + "')"
```

Comment: ok lo probare :)

Comment: cual version de SQL? Y puedes poner la structura de table prueba. Tambien el resultado de "print insert"

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, si me funciono tu respuesta, lo otro del max leght era un error mio :)

Comment: Perfecto! Feliz de poder ayudar